# How to use set_levels() after a drop() in a pandas dataframe ? Possible bug?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a complex pandas multiindex dataframe on which I want to change some column names. I use set_levels() for that and it works.

However, if before using the set_levels() function I use drop() to remove some unwanted columns, then the set_levels() gives me a strange error. I have tried with an elementary example and there it works, so I don't know what is particular in my specific dataframe.

I have trying to use reindex() and to use a temporary intermediate dataframe with copy() but it didn't solve the issue.

Is this a known bug?

Here is the issue more in detail:

My dataframe:

```
balanceData_a1b
```

[image: dataframe]
(the not-in-the-screen 2100 columns are the same as the 2015 ones)

If I use set_levels() to change the first column, it works without problems:

```
balanceData_a1b.columns.set_levels([ [2015, 2100], ['changed_name','dt','rev','rt_in','rt_out','sa','st','avg_price']], inplace=True)
```

[image: dataframe]

If instead, before running set_levels(), I drop the 'rev' columns I have the error:

```
balanceData_a1b.drop([(2015,'rev')],axis=1, inplace=True) 
balanceData_a1b.drop([(2100,'rev')],axis=1, inplace=True)
balanceData_a1b
```

[image: dataframe]

```
balanceData_a1b.columns.set_levels([ [2015, 2100], ['changed_name','dt','rt_in','rt_out','sa','st','avg_price']], inplace=True)
# notice that compared to the first attempt I removed here the 'rev' column, as I dropped it
```

[image: error]

What I did notice is that when I drop the columns, the dataframe is shown without the 'rev' dropped columns, but the columns property still shows them:

```
balanceData_a1b.columns
```

[image]

Is this the expected behaviour (e.g. due to some caching?) If so, how to update the column index ?

Comment: Yes, it is bug - [see](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2770)

Comment: Not a bug; this is defined behavior. Please read the issue fully.

Comment: After having read the issue, I personally believe it to be a bug.. or at least it is something that I would prefer it is handled differently: maybe a parameter in drop() that specify that I REALLY want get rid of that level and never hear about it any more ??